# wxpython & threads: How to simulate a trigger of an wx.EVT_BUTTON?

Tags: multithreading, wxpython

If I have a 'parent' window (wxFrame), and a plugin window.

(parent.py)

```
class App(wx.App):
            wxctrl = xrc.XRCCTRL( self.x_panel, "BUTTON")
            wx.EVT_BUTTON(wxctrl, wxctrl.GetId(),
                       self.OnButton)
```

How could I send an event from plugin.py that mimics clicking 'Button'?

Answer (score 0):

The class [`wx.Control`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxcontrol.html#wxcontrol) (base class of `wx.Button`) has a function `Command` that simulates a command event. Try this one

```
event = wx.CommandEvent(wx.EVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, self.wxctrl.GetId())
self.wxctrl.Command(event)
```

I'm not sure about the python syntax (programming in the C++ version of wxWidgets normally). But that's the rough plan.